# WP: Identify both page and a page parent by name (if statement)

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, parent-child

I'm trying to display content based on the current Wordpress page or subpage, working with page titles instead of IDs.

What I have is this:

```
<?php if ( is_page( array( 'About', 'Chi Siamo' ) ) || ( get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) == ( array( 'About', 'Chi Siamo' ) ) ) ) { ?>
<p>Hello Joe</p>
<?php } else {} ?>
```

Not sure why, but it's working on identifying the page names, but not the subpages of that page.

Can anyone see what I may have done wrong? Syntax error?

Thanks

PS. I have also tried

```
<?php if (get_the_title() || get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) == array( 'About', 'Chi Siamo' ) ) { ?>
```

But this returns true for all pages.

Comment: your first conditional seems a little parentheses happy

Comment: True :) I'm having trouble identifying child pages by their parent page name because there is no built-in function that does that - can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the outer parentheses from the second part of your conditional: `( get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) == ( array( 'About', 'Chi Siamo' ) ) )` and make sure `$post` is actually what you think it is.

Try to `var_dump($post)` and see if `post_parent` is actually present.

It's ugly to check for pages by title (slug or id would really be preferable), especially when it comes to finding their ancestors. The beauty of PHP is that it is dynamic, and you wont need to be manually changing IDs with each theme install.  Why not get the ID of the current page and then pass it to [get_ancestors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)?

Store that array in a variable, maybe `$ancestors`, and then `$ancestors[0]` will be the ID of the parent page. `get_the_title` of that ID, and then check if that is 'About' or 'Chi Siamo'.

**Update:**

Here's my previous answer in copyable code form:

```
$ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID);
$parent_id = $ancestors[0]
$parent_title = get_the_title($parent_id);
```

and then your conditional

```
if ( is_page(array('About', 'Chi Siamo' )) || $parent_title == 'About' || $parent_title == 'Chi Siamo') {
    echo '<p>Howdy</p>';
} else {}
```

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me a bit there. A function would be great, would something like this work? 'function parent_title() {
 $parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
 return $parent_title;
}

Comment: It could! Why don't you try it? Also, did you `var_dump($post)` to see if it had any value for the `post_parent` key?

Comment: Thanks very much, I've marked this as answered, will give this a shot this week.

Answer (score 0):

bit confused on why would you want to use post title's to do this, since post titles are not unique, two pages can have the same title.And if one of them has subpages and other doesn't the output wont be the desired one

Comment: Thanks suvajit, it's a bit of an interesting matter - my theme is going to be rolled out across several franchise sites. Without having to change page IDs every time I install, I'm trying to use arrays of page names in different languages. For the above, it's an 'About Us' page in English and Italian.